# Node js sll проблема переносимости кода

Tags: node.js, ssl, express

Код снизу корректно работает на Node.JS v0.10.36 - от сервера приходят ответы на https запросы, но на Node.JS v4.2.1 код работает не так как ожидалось, сервер не отвечает на запросы, но держит подключение (страничка все время грузится). В чем здесь ошибка или проблема переносимости кода?

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
//var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto=require('crypto')
var app = express();
var ssl_conf=require(__dirname+'/config/ssl.json');

var secureContext = {}

try{
    for(var domain in ssl_conf){
        secureContext[domain]=getSecureContext(ssl_conf[domain].domain);
    }
}
catch(err){
    console.log('error with ssl.config file '+err);

}

function getSecureContext (domain) {//returns secure context
    return crypto.createCredentials({
        key:  fs.readFileSync('./ssl/'+domain+'.key'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/'+domain+'.crt')
      }).context;
}

var options = {
    SNICallback: function (domain) {
        return secureContext[domain];
    },
//in case SNI is not available use this cert 
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/2_default.crt'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/2_default.key')
    }

app.get('/',function(req,res){//simple route
    res.send("your domain is "+req.hostname);
})

https.createServer(options, app).listen(443,function(){//run server
    console.log('https server running on 443')  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, вы вместе с Nodejs обновили Express.js.

Вот что мне написал мой Express 4.13.3, когда я попытался запустить ваш код:

```
express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead
```

Используйте `res.end(response)` вместо `res.send(response)`, либо комбинацию из `res.send(response)` для отправки ответа и `res.end()` для окончания запроса. В  Express 4 немного изменили этот механизм по сравнению с предыдущей версией.

Еще можно поставить express.js 3.x.x, все должно снова заработать (как вариант, для ленивых).

Comment: надо заменить часть кода приведенного выше на следующий

`var options = {
 SNICallback:function(domain,cb){
  console.log('here again');
  console.log(secureContext[domain])
  var ctx= tls.createSecureContext(
    secureContext[domain]
   ).context 
  if(cb)
   cb(null,ctx)
  else
   return ctx;
 }
}`
там другая сигнатура функции  SNICallback